# Silverlight Out of Browser check

Tags: silverlight

I am working on an application that requires running out of browser; How can I test if the application is running Out of Browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property on the `Application` object:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current.IsRuningOutOfBrowser)
{
    // The app is out of browser
}
```